Exception has occurred: TclError invalid command name ".!listbox"
I have two files, in one of which some numbers are generated and they are sent to another file, but in the insert operation, it gives an error to the listbox.
import a2 
for i in range(1,100,1):
    a2.ins(i)

from tkinter import *



root = Tk() 
root.title("Wallet")
root.configure(height='300px', width='1300px',bd=10)
root.geometry('1300x300')
root.resizable(0,0)
list1 = Listbox(root,width='1300',height='250')
list1.pack()
def ins(value):
    print(f"a2 : {value}")
    list1.insert(END,value)

root.mainloop()




Hello . I have two files, in one of which some numbers are generated and they are sent to another file, but in the insert operation, it gives an error to the listbox.

If the second code block is a2.py, then the for loop in first code block will not be executed until the window (created when a2 is imported) is destroyed.  So after the window is destroyed, calling a2.ins(i) will raise the exception.


I have two files, in one of which some numbers are generated and they
are sent to another file, but in the insert operation, it gives an
error to the listbox.

The problem can be fixed.
The first code block must be executed. So, you need to add a namespace tkinter.
Snippet:
import a2
import tkinter as tk

for i in range(1,100,1):
    a2.ins(i)

tk.mainloop()

The second block comment out mainloop()
Snippet:
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() 
root.title("Wallet")
root.configure(height='300px', width='1300px',bd=10)
root.geometry('1300x300')
root.resizable(0,0)
list1 = Listbox(root,width='1300',height='250')
list1.pack()
def ins(value):
    print(f"a2 : {value}")
    list1.insert(END,value)
 
#root.mainloop()

Screenshot:


The error was not resolved and it still gives errors

I updated. See my my answer. Did you add this import tkinter as tk in main form? Can you copy and paste?

It was fixed and the code worked without error, thank you

Glad you got it working.
